# change version of web services

Tags: c#, asp.net

my problem is I want to install the copy of the web service which is currently running on the server. I built the copy of the web service again and got a setup file. But if we tried to install that service on the server, it shows an error, saying a version is already installed in the system. I changed the name of the service, but doesn't work

Comment: I think you have to first uninstall the existing service, then try installing new one.

Comment: @UsmanWaheed sir i have to run 2 services at the same time..which having same functionality.need is only to change the name but it doesnt works

Comment: try these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945387/axis2-two-different-webservices-sharing-the-same-name http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369701/how-can-i-have-two-separate-web-services-with-identical-name-space-and-local-nam